# How to change NumberFormat from especific currency to a dollar currency

Tags: java, money-format

I have this block of code

> double price = rs.getDouble("price");
>
> NumberFormat nf= NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
>
> String formatedPrice = nf.format(price);
>
> buff.append("( " + formatedPrice + ")");

When I run the code everything works fine but the currency is set to for example:
( C800 ). I guess is because my country has the "Colon" for currency, but that is a thing from the past we now use the Dollar currency. So how can I change the currency to show this: ($400) instead of this (C300). Thanks very much for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use instead:

```
NumberFormat nf= NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Works like a charm thanks to all for your answers. I can't give points to all because I'm noob.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using US dollar you can use `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US)`

Answer (score 1):

You can add a locale as parameter to getCurrencyInstance:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can default it to $

Here is the solution

```
    double price = rs.getDouble("price");
    NumberFormat nf= NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(Locale.US);
        nf.setCurrency(currency);
        String formatedPrice = nf.format(price);
         System.out.println("( " + formatedPrice + ")");
```

Here is the solution